# Review required by 2 when a user with less than 2k Rep Edits the Question on StackOverFlow

Tags: discussion

I have been thinking about it lately. Maybe it has already been answered, but i couldn't find it anywhere.

What is the reason behind answer being reviewed by *Two Users* with more than *2k Rep*s when they already have privilege to edit that question and their edit will be applied instantly.

To clarify what I am asking:

- I am trying to answer a Question. The formatting is not well within the walls of correct and readable.
- I try to Edit the Question, but an edit approval is already pending.
- Now if I Approve the `Edit`, It still asks for another approval before it is applied, but if I `edit` the question or use `Improve Editing` then the Edit is applied instantly.

Now if I approve the `Edit`, i can't see the Question properly unless someone else reviews the `Edit`. And it doesn't seem ethical to Improve Edit the Question when it is already edited with perfection and disregard the efforts by previous editor.

Why can't the `edits` be applied instantly after 1st Review by a user with more than 2k Rep ?